# Node ssh to mysql - Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:3306

Tags: mysql, node.js, ssh

My API pulls data from a mysql database on a different server (both are hosted by Digital Ocean). I use the npm packages tunnel-ssh and mysql to access the database. It has been working fine but now (seemingly out of the blue) I am getting this error:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:3306
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1262:14)
    at listen (net.js:1298:10)
    at net.js:1408:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:83:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/project/project-server/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:154:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306
```

Here is the code:

```
let sshConf = {
  username: username,
  password: password,
  host: hostIP,
  port: 22,
  dstHost: sqlConf.host,
  dstPort: sqlConf.port
};

let server = tunnel(sshConf, function(error){
  if(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
  /* would establish connection to database here */
});

server.on('error', function(err){
  console.error('Something bad happened:', err); // error is caught here
});
```

I looked for a process on the database server that could be using the address. I've tried killing the processes but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
$ lsof -i:3306
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  1962 mysql   41u  IPv4  21608      0t0  TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)
mysqld  1962 mysql   49u  IPv4  22456      0t0  TCP localhost:mysql->localhost:56380 (ESTABLISHED)
mysqld  1962 mysql   50u  IPv4  22458      0t0  TCP localhost:mysql->localhost:56382 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    2068  root    8u  IPv4  22455      0t0  TCP localhost:56380->localhost:mysql (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    2068  root    9u  IPv4  22457      0t0  TCP localhost:56382->localhost:mysql (ESTABLISHED)
```

I've also tried restarting the database server. I am still able to access the database remotely using MySQLWorkbench. I can't for the life of me figure out what I've done to cause this. If I changed any configuration on the database server it wasn't intentional.

Any ideas of further troubleshooting I can do?

Comment: MySQL, PID 1962, is what's listening on 3306.  (`lsof` is being "helpful" here by replacing `:3306` with `mysql`.)  It would be better to use a normal SSH tunnel over Digital Ocean's private networking (if both instances are in the same region) than to implement this in the application layer.

Comment: @Brad I had read it was more secure to have your API and database on separate servers and tunnel-ssh was my "solution" to access the data in the database. I guess I have more research to do! I tried stopping mysqld (sudo mysqld stop) to see how that would effect the error but it restarted again. In terms of making my api functional again I'm not sure how to move forward. If I shutdown mysqld then I don't have a database server. I wish I knew what happened to cause this. I tried several earlier commits in my project but that didn't fix the issue. I also tried cloning to a different server.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can avoid having to listen locally altogether by using the `ssh2` module directly with the `mysql2` module, since the latter allows you to supply any Duplex stream to use as the underlying socket connection. `ssh2` can give you such a stream when you make an outgoing TCP connection over the ssh connection.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done to fix this temporarily is change the port in /etc/mysql/my.cnf to 3307. I would really love to know how to have fixed this without changing the port though.

I am going to follow @Brad 's suggestion and work on connecting the api server and database server over Digital Ocean's private network.